# How to collect JMX metrics from metrics endpoint of Kafka using Telegraf input plugin

Tags: plugins, apache-kafka, influxdb, telegraf

I am using **TICK** stack.
I have to import data from kafka metrics endpoint to Influx DB. Can I do it without  integrate jolokia telegraf plugin. I have all instances running in k8s.
Is there a way too use metrics endpoint and put data to influx DB?

Comment: I want something very similar to jmx Prometheus exporter

Answer (score 0):

Kafka exposes its [metrics using JMX](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/monitoring.html), which you can send to InfluxDB with [jxmterm](https://github.com/jmxtrans/jmxtrans/wiki/InfluxDBWriter).